# Is there a way to encrypt a file using Seahorse without installing the "seahorse-plugins" package?

Tags: seahorse

Seahorse came preinstalled on my default installation of Ubuntu. But I can find no way to encrypt a file using it.  I am wanting to use a GUI I don't want to do it using the Terminal. Creating the private key and signing public keys can all be done in Seahorse GUI.

Is there a way to also encrypt files using this interface, or do I NEED to install the seahorse-plugins package to have a GUI method of encrypting?

Comment: Seahorse is a GUI for GnuPG. Are you looking for another GUI program to encrypt files, or is a commandline tool sufficient?

Comment: Look for the "Add Comment" button beneath our comments, its in grey text.  @Lekensteyn: In the event the answer below gets erased (because its really just a comment) he wants a GUI solution, but also seems to want to use seahorse to do it all.

Comment: There is a specific reason to not install `seahorse-plugins`?

Comment: @Sam is there any specific reasons you do not want to install `seahorse-plugins`?

Comment: no specific reason other than I don't want to install anything if its superfluous. If there's a way to do it without seahorse-plugins (non-terminal) I'd like to try that way out before installing it. From the lacks of answers, I'm assuming there is no way to encrypt without the plugins package?

Comment: The terminal command is simply `gpg -e file` to encrypt a file once you have the keys generated.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: For me the same question is interesting, because it seems as seahorse plugins only work with the gnome file managers. But I am using LXDE. So: Is there a possibility to use it with pcmanfm, the file manager LXDE uses?